# How to detect when a TextView is selected but before it becomes first responder?

Tags: ios, swift, xml, interface-builder

I want a scrollview to move in sync with the keyboard.  In order to move it to the correct spot, I need to get a reference to the textview that is the first responder.  If I get the reference after it becomes first responder, then the scroll lags behind the appearance of the keyboard.  If I assign the first responder to a variable after the textview becomes first responder, then the first responder reference won't be available when the keyboard moves.

Comment: "If I assign the first responder after the textview becomes first responder" assign the first responder to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your first responder reference before system shows the keyboard using [`UITextViewDelegate.textViewShouldBeginEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618608-textviewshouldbeginediting)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var currentFirstResponder: UITextView?
    
    // iOS will call this before it shows keyboard
    // If you return true, it will show keyboard
    // If you return false, it will not show keyboard
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        currentFirstResponder = textView
        return true
    }
}
```